# SQL to Entities - cannot make 'String.Contains' return 'case-INSENSITIVE' results

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities, collation

I have a C# application that performs 'LINQ to Entities' queries.

The database it is connected to is MS SQL 2012.
The database collation is 'Hebrew CI'.

And still - if I perform a query like:

```
return users.Where(us => us.FirstName.Contains("joh"));
```

it does not fetch the records with 'FirstName' that has **'John'**. Only the ones with first name **'john'**.

I thought that this is determined on the SQL Server-side by the database collation, but obviously I am wrong ...

Also -  I have checked the 'FirstName' column's collation, and it is set to 'Database Default'.

What am I missing here ?

.

**[ UPDATE ]**

After reading some comments - I need to clarify :

I am using LINQ-TO-ENTITIES, not a local query.

The full piece of code is :

```
public List<User>   GetUsersByName(IMyDBEntities context, String filterBy)
{
    IEnumerable<User> users = context.Users;

    return users.Where(us => us.FirstName.Contains("filterBy"));  // filterBy = 'joh'
}
```

The full function contains more filters (filter by age, filter by address, etc...)

which all happen on the 'server' list of users, and only when I do '.ToList()' does the query actually fire with all the filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, you are executing this Where call on a local collection, meaning you get LINQ to Objects semantics. You need to move it to a database query.

Seeing the updated code the problem is apparent:

```
IEnumerable<User>
```

By declaring the sequence variable to be a local sequence, not a query, you make the compiler use local query operators, not remote query operators.

The compile-time type must be `IQueryable<User>`.

Comment: Like I told @Alexander - I have updated my question to contain some more code. As you can see - the list of 'users' is NOT a local list of objects. I simply stack more and more filters on the 'context.Users' table, and then fire the '.ToList' method to make it query the database with all the filters ... so again - from what I understand - I should be looking at some problem on the database side, no ?

Comment: I have added the solution to my post. You might want to research this aspect of LINQ a bit to gain some deeper insights on why this happens.

Comment: Problem solved, @usr. You are a genius :)  Can you clarify a bit more what the problem was using 'IEnumerable' ? Can you refer me to some links that can shed some light on it ?

Comment: and is it true to say that I can stack more and more filters on an 'IQueryable' collection, that only when I convert to '.ToList' will run ON THE DATABASE ?

Comment: You can "stack" queries (compose them). This is a great strength of LINQ.; The compile time type will determine how your query executes. Enumerable.* methods are L2Objects, Queryable.* usually translate to your ORM. If you have an `IEnumerable<User>`, what do you think will be called? (Answer: Enumerable.* of course!).; The sql query executes as soon as you enumerate the IQueryable. ToList internally does just that. Nothing special about ToList here. Other examples are First and Single.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve this:

```
return users.Where(us => us.FirstName.ToLower().Contains("joh"));
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for all Unicode characters. It is better to use a StringComparison (then it will work!).

Comment: @usr - Not when you just want to use `Contains`. There is no overload that takes `StringComparison`.

Comment: Yeah the OP needs to construct that one himself using IndexOf(...) != -1

Comment: @Oded - Doesn't this solution make the server perform a text operation on ALL of the rows in the table in order to perform the comparison ? isn't this very bad in 'performance' terms just to look up a row ?

Answer (score 0):

If this linq is mapped to sql, it will use sql server settings...but in your case, `users` is already a list of objects (otherwise your string compare would be database server dependent), so you can do something like this:

```
return users.Where(us => us.FirstName.Contains("joh", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: I have updated my question to contain some more code. As you can see - the list of 'users' is not a local list of objects. I simply stack more and more filters on the 'context.Users' table, and then fire the '.ToList' method to make it query the database with all the filters ... so again - from what I understand - I should be looking at some problem on the database side, no ?

Comment: Get generated sql query by calling: var query = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)the_variable_that_you_return).ToTraceString(); and try to execute it directly against sql server. If it doesn't work, start to look for solution on the sql server side.